# regexp_replace in snowflake to replace the character in angle bracket

Tags: sql, regex, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

```
11223335 <!---->
22321<!---->
123<span _ngcontent-pyp-c88="" class="fid ng-star-inserted">/ parent force id: <a _ngcontent-py>
123<span _ngcontent-pyp-c88="" class="fid ng-star-inserted">/ parent force id: <a _ngcontent-py>
12323970 <!---->
123<!---->
```

I need to replace the characters in the angle bracket with empty string.

```
select ga_dimension16, regexp_replace(collate(ga_dimension16,''),
'([[:digit:]]{6,7}).>$','')
from stageABC where ga_dimension16 like '%<%'
```

Comment: Why do you have `([[:digit:]]{6,7})` in your regexp? That's for matching 6 or 7 digits, which has nothing to do with matching angle brackets.

Comment: Please include expected output in your question

Answer (score 0):

to replace the characters inside the angle brackets with an empty string try this way:

```
SELECT
  ga_dimension16,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(ga_dimension16, '<[^>]+>', '') as replaced_ga_dimension16
FROM
  stageABC;
```

Comment: Thank you Nadir. What if want to replace all the character that come after First angle brackets.

Comment: Re "*to replace the characters inside the angle brackets with an empty string*", That replaces the brackets too. To keep the brackets, use `REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '<[^>]+>', '<>')` /// On the other hand, i f you want to remove the brackets, then it should be `REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '<[^>]*>', '')` (`*`, not `+`).

Comment: @Arun, Re "*What if want to replace all the character that come after First angle brackets.*", `REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '<.*', '<')`

Comment: @ikegami What about this case? 

66556498<!--bindings={   "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false" }-->
it repalced only half on this case

Comment: @Arun, For that input, you would get `66556498<` as requested. If there's a line break you might have to use a special flag to make `.` match it, or use a hack like `[\S\s]` instead of `.`.